# How to find out the PK & indexes on table/data-to-insights:ecommerce.web_analytics?

Tags: google-bigquery

I cannot run an efficient query on a table. I am not aware of how to find out what are the primary key, other keys and indexes defined on a table. How to find indexes defined on the `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics` table?

I am trying a query like below which should get just one record, to find some concrete sample data to play with, and be efficient at the same time. It always says to increase the max bytes to at least 30MB or so. But according to a previous query result, for which I increased to 30MB, the result should be one row. Can one row be this big? Is it trying to scan the whole table? How to find out indexes?

I executed this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  wa.date,
  fullVisitorId
FROM
  `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics` AS wa
WHERE
  wa.date='20161128'
GROUP BY
  wa.date,
  fullVisitorId
LIMIT
  100
```

I get a result table with pairs of date + visitorId and count(*)=1 for each pair. Then I execute this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  wa.date,
  fullVisitorId
FROM
  `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics` AS wa
WHERE
  wa.date='20161128'
  AND wa.fullVisitorId='5244450947123722944'
GROUP BY
  wa.date,
  fullVisitorId
LIMIT
  100
```

In my understanding, this should get just one row from the table and it should (this I am not sure) go straight to it via an index like PK. Potentially some of this reasoning /assumption is not right, because when adding a WHERE criteria, the data it scans or it retrieves should decrease not increase.

It says it will need to consume 30MB which seems a lot for what I would think it is a row or a few. And indeed, when I allowed for 30MB, I saw that count(*) is 1 for a specific combination of date and fullVisitorId. But then when I filtered by a specific date and visitorId, again it says I need to let him spend 30MB. Why would this be? Is this more than one row? Is one row this big? Why is this MB quantity not decreasing when adding conditions (where clauses), but sometimes even increasing even though it should retrieve less data.

```
This query will process 28.6 MB when run.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note BigQuery is not a traditional relational database, it is a highly distributed storage and data analytics solution more similar to a column-based store. Thus, the concepts of primary key, foreign key, indexes, etc. does not exist in BigQuery.

BigQuery measures the total amount of data processed  (since this is the relevant metric for [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries)) and not the size of the result. When you set max bytes to 30 MB, you are not telling BigQuery to return at most 30 MBs, but to process at most 30 MB.

Addressing your questions:

- Can one row be this big?

Yes, it is possible.  But as mentioned above, 30 MB is a limit you are imposing to all the processed rows not to the resulting row.

- Is it trying to scan the whole table?

No, it would scan all the rows, but, since BigQuery has a column-based storage structure, it would only scan the columns you use in your query. For example, for your first query, it would scan all the rows in “wa” and “fullVisitorId”. For this reason, “Select *” queries are not recommended.

- How to find out indexes?

There are no indexes in BigQuery, you can use [clustered tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) though.

- Why would this be?

Because of the aforementioned BigQuery architecture.

- Is this more than one row? Is one row this big?

No and not likely

- Why is this MB quantity not decreasing when adding conditions (where clauses), but sometimes even increasing even though it should retrieve less data.

Because you are likely referencing more columns in your query, thus, additional columns need to be scanned.

I would recommend you to see the [BigQuery best practices for controlling costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs), since those explain how to make your queries process less data.